# Hugo template formatting in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, hugo

The auto format in VS Code is making my code unreadable by removing indentations. I don't know how to turn this off for handlebars only.

Input:

```
{{ range ... }}
   {{ if .... }}
      {{if ... }}
          <tag></tag>
      {{end}}
   {{end}}
{{end}}
```

Output

```
{{ range ... }}
{{ if .... }}
{{if ... }}
<tag></tag>
{{end}}
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

Any way to prevent this?

Comment: If you're using prettier that question should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431432/prettier-visual-code-settings-for-hugo-html-templates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the document type by using select Language Mode (change Language Mode `ctrl + k + m`), set the language to HTML template HTML Twig.

Then do formating, it will format perfect.
It worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, I would note that you need to get the extension "PHP Twig" for it to show up, simply searching for HTML Twig won't return anything.

Comment: shortcut to set the language does not work.. how to set the language without shortcuts and even when I did long way or by settings json it still didn't work.  However.. selecting language "go" from HTML in the lower right corner did work.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a clean way to do this, but the kludgy work around I found is to use the `html.format.contentUnformatted` setting in my workspace with a custom html tag.

```
"settings": {
        "html.format.contentUnformatted": "ignore-format"
}
```

And then wrap sections of templating code that need formatting inside this tag.

```html
<ignore-format>
{{ range ... }}
   {{ if .... }}
      {{if ... }}
          <tag></tag>
      {{end}}
   {{end}}
{{end}}
</ignore-format>
```

Note that I chose `ignore-format`, this can be any valid custom html tag name. If you find a cleaner solution, please let me know and I'll mark your answer as accepted.