# Prettier & Visual Code settings for Hugo HTML templates

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, hugo, prettier

I generally like using Prettier with Visual Code.  However, Prettier is making me crazy while editing HTML templates for Hugo because it will not preserve the reader friendly formatting of this:

```
  {{ with .Site.Params.author }}<meta name="author" content="{{ . }}">{{ end }}
  {{ hugo.Generator }}

  {{ "<!-- plugins -->" | safeHTML }}
  {{ range .Site.Params.plugins.css }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ .URL | absURL }} ">
  {{ end }}

  {{ "<!-- Main Stylesheet -->" | safeHTML }}
  {{ $styles := resources.Get "scss/style.scss" | toCSS | minify | fingerprint }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ $styles.Permalink }}" integrity="{{ $styles.Data.Integrity }}" media="screen">
```

Instead it is transformed to:

```
  {{ with .Site.Params.author }}
  <meta name="author" content="{{ . }}" />
  {{ end }} {{ hugo.Generator }} {{ "
  <!-- plugins -->
  " | safeHTML }} {{ range .Site.Params.plugins.css }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ .URL | absURL }} " />
  {{ end }} {{ "
  <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
  " | safeHTML }} {{ $styles := resources.Get "scss/style.scss" | toCSS | minify
  | fingerprint }}
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="{{ $styles.Permalink }}"
    integrity="{{ $styles.Data.Integrity }}"
    media="screen"
  />
```

How can Prettier be customized to better handle template logic?  (I have since resorted to disabling it.)

Comment: I found a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980680/hugo-template-formatting-in-vs-code

Answer (score 9):

I also got really annoyed by prettier breaking our GoHugo html files. The plugin below fixes the behavior.

[prettier-plugin-go-template](https://github.com/NiklasPor/prettier-plugin-go-template)

---

If you're using plain `*.html` files, you'll want to pay attention to the `GoHugo` section of the Readme:

> To use it with GoHugo and basic `.html` files, you'll have to override
> the used parser inside your `.prettierrc` file:

```
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "options": {
        "parser": "go-template"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for making this template. I wasn't able to get it working going by the readme, so I would benefit greatly if you were to make a VSCode extension as you were considering.

Comment: If you want to set it up globally, this will probably help: https://github.com/NiklasPor/prettier-plugin-go-template/issues/58#issuecomment-1085060511